# same script and software throws exception on windows

Tags: php, mysql, windows, zend-framework, wamp

i install my software on linux its working fine with the same data base but in windows wamp it throws the the following error. need some help here

```
Application error

Exception information:

Message: Mysqli prepare error: Unknown column 'Employee.Attendance_ID'
in 'on clause'

Stack trace:

#0 C:\wamp\www\AMS\library\Zend\Db\Statement.php(115): Zend_Db_Statement_Mysqli->_prepare('SELECT ??????(S...')
#1 C:\wamp\www\AMS\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Mysqli.php(381): Zend_Db_Statement->__construct(Object(Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli), 'SELECT ??????(S...')
#2 C:\wamp\www\AMS\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(478): Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli->prepare('SELECT ??????(S...')
#3 C:\wamp\www\AMS\application\modules\default\models\Employee.php(242):
Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT ??????(S...', '2014-06-13')
#4 C:\wamp\www\AMS\application\modules\default\controllers\IndexController.php(12):
Default_Model_Employee->todaysAttendance()
5 C:\wamp\www\AMS\library\Zend\Controller\Action.php(516): Default_IndexController->indexAction()
#6 C:\wamp\www\AMS\library\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php(295):
Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('indexAction')
#7 C:\wamp\www\AMS\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http),
Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#8 C:\wamp\www\AMS\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php(97):
Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#9 C:\wamp\www\AMS\library\Zend\Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#10 C:\wamp\www\AMS\index.php(40): Zend_Application->run()
#11 {main}   Request Parameters:



array ( 'controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index', 'module' => 'default', )
```

Comment: the software is working fine on linux but in windows its not

Comment: Either you have connected to the wrong database or you have not properly restored the database. Its saying that `Employee.Attendance_ID` does not exist.

Comment: no the same script is running on linux